# Filter pipe for async data in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, filter, pipe

I use a pipe to filter a table into which the data comes asynchronously from the server, and until the data arrives, the tunnel continuously returns undefined:
[image]

My pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], userName): any {
        console.log('Usernames', userName);

        return userName
            ? items.filter(item => item.displayUsername.indexOf(userName) !== -1)
            : items;
    }
}
```

And where i use it:

```
<input type="text"
name="userName"
[(ngModel)]="userName">

<div
 *ngFor="let user of (users | async | filter: userName );"
>
```

And this has a very bad effect on application performance.

Maybe I understand the work of pipe is not entirely correct, but
how do I rewrite a pipe so that it returns values only when the text is entered into the input?

Comment: By following the advice of the documentation, and not using a pipe to filter: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe